# Can you set scroll-padding-top for a specific subsection of a scroll container?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site that is edited as markdown. Headings are all assigned an `id` automatically, which allows bookmark links to specific headings...

```
/page-name#bookmark-id
```

There is a sticky header on the site, so there is a `scroll-padding-top` set to ensure the heading is within view when a bookmark is followed.

[image: Sticky header isn't a problem as scroll-padding makes sure the heading is visible]

## A grid of cards

However, if you have a grid of cards with an image displayed above the heading, a different `scroll-padding-top` is needed, but not for the whole page - just for the part where the images *also* need to be accounted for.

Desired result:

[image: More scroll padding is needed just for one section]

This is what actually happens:

[image: Images are not visible because they have been scrolled past]

## Code

I can't find a way to accommodate this as scroll padding is added to the scroll container. The normal headings work, but I want to make the images visible when a card bookmark is followed...

Is it possible to change the scroll padding for one section of a scroll container? Can it be solved some other way?

```css
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 100px;
}

.something-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.something-griddy {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}

.something-cardy {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}

.example-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="something-sticky">
<h1>This is the sticky header</h1>
</div>

<p>Hopefully this will demonstrate the general issue...</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#a-normal-heading">A normal heading</a></li>
  <li><a href="#another-normal-heading">Another normal heading</a></li>
  <li><a href="#card-heading">Card heading</a></li>
</ul>

<h2 id="a-normal-heading">A normal heading</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac lorem non enim porta efficitur non nec arcu. Nulla condimentum magna a tortor rhoncus, ac vestibulum nibh blandit. Nam sagittis nisi ac commodo dapibus. Proin lacinia mauris lacus. Donec et mauris enim. Sed efficitur justo dolor. Vivamus dignissim ligula vestibulum, luctus nibh in, facilisis leo. Pellentesque consequat dignissim lorem, et congue diam aliquam sed. Etiam facilisis, nibh non efficitur feugiat, tortor diam gravida sem, rutrum pretium mi risus quis odio. Quisque aliquet at tellus ac convallis.</p>

<p>Etiam vitae pulvinar purus. Aliquam auctor felis ante, vitae molestie purus iaculis at. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus tincidunt, nisi nec viverra tincidunt, ligula ligula rhoncus velit, non sollicitudin elit dolor quis nibh. Donec venenatis iaculis lorem vitae tincidunt. Ut consectetur est sed orci convallis venenatis. Mauris sit amet placerat justo, nec suscipit ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>

<h2 id="another-normal-heading">Another normal heading</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac lorem non enim porta efficitur non nec arcu. Nulla condimentum magna a tortor rhoncus, ac vestibulum nibh blandit. Nam sagittis nisi ac commodo dapibus. Proin lacinia mauris lacus. Donec et mauris enim. Sed efficitur justo dolor. Vivamus dignissim ligula vestibulum, luctus nibh in, facilisis leo. Pellentesque consequat dignissim lorem, et congue diam aliquam sed. Etiam facilisis, nibh non efficitur feugiat, tortor diam gravida sem, rutrum pretium mi risus quis odio. Quisque aliquet at tellus ac convallis.</p>

<p>Etiam vitae pulvinar purus. Aliquam auctor felis ante, vitae molestie purus iaculis at. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus tincidunt, nisi nec viverra tincidunt, ligula ligula rhoncus velit, non sollicitudin elit dolor quis nibh. Donec venenatis iaculis lorem vitae tincidunt. Ut consectetur est sed orci convallis venenatis. Mauris sit amet placerat justo, nec suscipit ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
<div class="something-griddy">

<div class="something-cardy">
<div class="example-image">IMAGE</div>
<h2 id="card-heading">Card heading</h2>
</div>

<div class="something-cardy">
<div class="example-image">IMAGE</div>
<h2 id="card-heading-2">Card heading 2</h2>
</div>

<div class="something-cardy">
<div class="example-image">IMAGE</div>
<h2 id="card-heading-3">Card heading 3</h2>
</div>

</div>

<h2>More content to ensure scrollbars...</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac lorem non enim porta efficitur non nec arcu. Nulla condimentum magna a tortor rhoncus, ac vestibulum nibh blandit. Nam sagittis nisi ac commodo dapibus. Proin lacinia mauris lacus. Donec et mauris enim. Sed efficitur justo dolor. Vivamus dignissim ligula vestibulum, luctus nibh in, facilisis leo. Pellentesque consequat dignissim lorem, et congue diam aliquam sed. Etiam facilisis, nibh non efficitur feugiat, tortor diam gravida sem, rutrum pretium mi risus quis odio. Quisque aliquet at tellus ac convallis.</p>

<p>Etiam vitae pulvinar purus. Aliquam auctor felis ante, vitae molestie purus iaculis at. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus tincidunt, nisi nec viverra tincidunt, ligula ligula rhoncus velit, non sollicitudin elit dolor quis nibh. Donec venenatis iaculis lorem vitae tincidunt. Ut consectetur est sed orci convallis venenatis. Mauris sit amet placerat justo, nec suscipit ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac lorem non enim porta efficitur non nec arcu. Nulla condimentum magna a tortor rhoncus, ac vestibulum nibh blandit. Nam sagittis nisi ac commodo dapibus. Proin lacinia mauris lacus. Donec et mauris enim. Sed efficitur justo dolor. Vivamus dignissim ligula vestibulum, luctus nibh in, facilisis leo. Pellentesque consequat dignissim lorem, et congue diam aliquam sed. Etiam facilisis, nibh non efficitur feugiat, tortor diam gravida sem, rutrum pretium mi risus quis odio. Quisque aliquet at tellus ac convallis.</p>

<p>Etiam vitae pulvinar purus. Aliquam auctor felis ante, vitae molestie purus iaculis at. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus tincidunt, nisi nec viverra tincidunt, ligula ligula rhoncus velit, non sollicitudin elit dolor quis nibh. Donec venenatis iaculis lorem vitae tincidunt. Ut consectetur est sed orci convallis venenatis. Mauris sit amet placerat justo, nec suscipit ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac lorem non enim porta efficitur non nec arcu. Nulla condimentum magna a tortor rhoncus, ac vestibulum nibh blandit. Nam sagittis nisi ac commodo dapibus. Proin lacinia mauris lacus. Donec et mauris enim. Sed efficitur justo dolor. Vivamus dignissim ligula vestibulum, luctus nibh in, facilisis leo. Pellentesque consequat dignissim lorem, et congue diam aliquam sed. Etiam facilisis, nibh non efficitur feugiat, tortor diam gravida sem, rutrum pretium mi risus quis odio. Quisque aliquet at tellus ac convallis.</p>

<p>Etiam vitae pulvinar purus. Aliquam auctor felis ante, vitae molestie purus iaculis at. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus tincidunt, nisi nec viverra tincidunt, ligula ligula rhoncus velit, non sollicitudin elit dolor quis nibh. Donec venenatis iaculis lorem vitae tincidunt. Ut consectetur est sed orci convallis venenatis. Mauris sit amet placerat justo, nec suscipit ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac lorem non enim porta efficitur non nec arcu. Nulla condimentum magna a tortor rhoncus, ac vestibulum nibh blandit. Nam sagittis nisi ac commodo dapibus. Proin lacinia mauris lacus. Donec et mauris enim. Sed efficitur justo dolor. Vivamus dignissim ligula vestibulum, luctus nibh in, facilisis leo. Pellentesque consequat dignissim lorem, et congue diam aliquam sed. Etiam facilisis, nibh non efficitur feugiat, tortor diam gravida sem, rutrum pretium mi risus quis odio. Quisque aliquet at tellus ac convallis.</p>

<p>Etiam vitae pulvinar purus. Aliquam auctor felis ante, vitae molestie purus iaculis at. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus tincidunt, nisi nec viverra tincidunt, ligula ligula rhoncus velit, non sollicitudin elit dolor quis nibh. Donec venenatis iaculis lorem vitae tincidunt. Ut consectetur est sed orci convallis venenatis. Mauris sit amet placerat justo, nec suscipit ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
```

Comment: Your anchor tag points to "#card-heading", why not give <div class="something-griddy"> an **id** and point to that ?

Comment: That's a good back up plan. It would require end-users to do something different (i.e. they'd need to use markdown extensions to insert the id's by hand). Ideally, I'd love to solve it without asking users to understand the problem.